# How speed-up python function (numpy)

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, computer-vision

I have grayscale image (matrix) and this function:

```
    sz1, sz2 = image_layer.shape
    x_end, y_end = (sz1 - N1 + 1), (sz2 - N1 + 1)
    Av = np.zeros((N1 * N1, x_end * y_end), dtype=complex)

    index = 0
    for x in range(x_end):
        for y in range(y_end):
            Av[:, index] = np.fft.fft2(image_layer[x: x + N1, y: y + N1]).flatten()
            index += 1
```

I want to speed up this function.

I tried different methods:

- multithreading
- multiprocessing
- cpython
- numba

I splitted x and y values on blocks but this doesn't help me.
I read about numpy.vectorize, but couldn't do it.

P.S. 100x100 matrix time: 0.23435211181640625 ms

P.S.S 1000x1000 matrix time: 28.731552600860596 ms

I think if I change the algorithm it will help speed up the function

Edited:
I want to make a block (8x8) for every element matrix and calculate fft2.

Comment: You have to get rid of the loops. I am not going to try to guess what the code is doing now, but you should probably edit your question to explain in detail what you want to achieve, including example input and output

Comment: The question is you call `np.fft.fft2` for more than one `x` or `y` value at once?